# Add entries to model with ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I been struggling with this for a while and can't seem to find an answer on any of the other threads.

I am trying to programmatically add some entries to a model in Django, the model I am trying to add to has a foreign key, and this is what I am getting hung up on.

My two models are:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    direct_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    post_url = models.URLField()
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    time_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I am trying to run some code to add some data I am pulling from another location in the DetailView (Class based view)

The code that I have for that is here:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post
for i in hot:
    if i.url.endswith(Endings):
        post_to = model.objects.get(direct_url=i.url)
        submission = reddit.submission(url=f'https://www.reddit.com/r/{i.permalink}')
        submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
        for comment in submission.comments.list():
            Comment.objects.create(post=f'{post_to}', content=f'{comment.body}', author=f'{comment.author}', date_created=f'{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(comment.created)}')
```

I am trying to pull the reddit comments, and store them in a database. The problem I am running into is the following:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Post object (22)'": "Comment.post" must be a "Post" instance.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the last line, you're formatting `post_to` to string and assigning it to `post` which must be a `Post` instance and not `str`. Just write `post=post_to`

Comment: I thought it wanted a string. This is embarrassing! lol. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: It happens to all of us mate, don't sweat it!

Comment: Now I am getting an error saying, "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: homepage_post" -- homepage is the name of my app.

Comment: Have you migrated your models correctly?

Comment: If I comment out the recent code in the views.py, everything works fine. With the code in there I cannot run manage.py makemigrations, or migrate. I have also tried to run the syncdb, but that isn't working either. It seems directly related to the code added in the views, as if I remove that code it works. I tried dropping the db and creating a new one but I still get the same error with the views.py code in there.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to manually run makemigrations on my app, makemigrations appname, after commenting out the code, and then I was able to access the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this meta directive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat), I have turned the following comment by [@Sajad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6906346/sajad) into a community wiki, signalling that this question is solved.

> In the last line, you're formatting `post_to` to string and assigning it to `post` which must be a `Post` instance and not str. Just write `post=post_to`.

The following code should work:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post
for i in hot:
    if i.url.endswith(Endings):
        post_to = model.objects.get(direct_url=i.url)
        submission = reddit.submission(url=f'https://www.reddit.com/r/{i.permalink}')
        submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
        for comment in submission.comments.list():
            Comment.objects.create(post=post_to, content=f'{comment.body}', author=f'{comment.author}', date_created=f'{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(comment.created)}')
```